# Printing from a derived class with a base class function

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

I am trying to print with a function from a function in a derived class with a function from the base class within it and I am not exactly sure if I should be
how I can print out both information from the Shape toString function and the Rectangle toString function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(double w, double h);
    string toString();

private:
    double width;
    double height;

};

Shape::Shape(double w, double h)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

string Shape::toString()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Width: " << width << endl;
    ss << "Height: " << height << endl;

    return ss.str();
}

class Rectangle : public Shape
{

public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h, int s);
string toString();

private:
    int sides;

};


string Rectangle::toString()
{
    //
    // Implement the Rectangle toString function
    // using the Shape toString function
    Shape::toString();
    cout << toString();
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Sides: " << sides << endl;
    return ss.str();

}

// Use the constructor you created
// for the previous problem here
Rectangle::Rectangle(double w, double h, int s)
    :Shape(w, h)
{
    sides = s;
}
```

The only parts that can be manipulated in the problem are the sections that come after the comments

Comment: What have you tried? What are you struggling to understand? Where have you searched for answers before asking on stack overflow?

Comment: have you tried `virtual` keyword?

Comment: @simple_code I've tried returning the two outputs added together...@vishal  I know you don't have to use a virtual keyword (we haven't gone over that yet). It seems right but gives me a run time error every time it compiles
    my main problem is in the `string Rectangle::toString()` section

Comment: Put the additions to the question not to new comments. Nobody wants to gather the question from that comments. -- Keep in mind, Stackoverflow is not a discussion but a question answer site.

Comment: @harper thanks for the input.... anything regarding the code itself?

Comment: How do you want to call what method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
cout << toString();
```

since it is going to recursively call itself and eventually you will run out of stack and get the runtime error.

your implementation should be:

```
string Rectangle::toString()
{
    // Implement the Rectangle toString function
    // using the Shape toString function
    stringstream ss;
    ss << Shape::toString();
    ss << "Sides: " << sides << endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Also consider making this method `const` and `virtual` in the case you want polymorphism to work properly.

Comment: @simple01 thanks, that fixed it. I didn't realize you could put multiple things into a stringstream.